# Python Pygame Random Imgs for Weather System

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, pygame

My 10 year old son is trying to implement new feature a weather system in this 2d game he made base off tutorial with pygame but is running into a IdententationError issue.

I been helping him but I am still learning also, I think it is the random and the display but I don't know how to fix it since is one of his first approach to pygame.

He is try to have it generate random weather to send across the screen. He also wants to add collision detection with player down the line but he still learning that subject.

**Here is his code:**
[all files](http://www.lincoln-cent.com/full-game.zip) I also included the original finished untouched the full edited one

**Problem area 1:**

Getting  IdententationError  line 259 which is this one

```
randomNumber = random.randint(0,20)
```

4 lines down from here

```
#a list of resources
WEATHER = [CLOUD,RAIN,THUNDER,TORNADO]

#loop through each weather type and choose weather type for it to be
        #pick a random number between 0 and 20
        randomNumber = random.randint(0,20)
        #if a zero, then the weather is TORNADO
        if randomNumber == 0:
            WEATHER = TORNADO
        #water if the random number is a 1 or a 2
        elif randomNumber in [1,2]:
            WEATHER = THUNDER
        elif randomNumber in [3,4,5,6,7,8]:
            WEATHER = RAIN
        else:
            WEATHER = CLOUD
```

**Problem area 2:**

```
#display the weather
DISPLAYSURF.blit(textures[WEATHER].convert_alpha(),(weatherx,weathery))
#move the cloud to the left slightly
weatherx+=1
#if the weather has moved past the map
if weatherx > MAPWIDTH*TILESIZE:
    #pick a new position to place the weather
    weathery = random.randint(0,(MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE) - 150)
    weatherx = -200
```

Below is the original cloud only system before he tried to add weather

```
#commented out the original cloud only weather system 
#display the cloud
DISPLAYSURF.blit(textures[CLOUD].convert_alpha(),(cloudx,cloudy))
#move the cloud to the left slightly
cloudx+=1
if the cloud has moved past the map
if cloudx > MAPWIDTH*TILESIZE:
    #pick a new position to place the cloud
    cloudy = random.randint(0,(MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE) - 150)
    cloudx = -200
```

**Other Parts Of the Code**

But not the full code below we believe to be correct

I import in pygame and the random and set clock

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *

fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

I load in the weather off screen

```
#weather position
weatherx = -200
weathery = 0
```

The Choices of Weather Types which I can add more down the line ex snow, etc

```
   #the number of each weather type that we have
weather =   {
                CLOUD    : 0,
                RAIN     : 0,
                THUNDER  : 0,
                TORNADO  : 0
                         }
```

This is how I add the texture or png images I left out the many others

```
DIRT    : pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Daddy\\Documents\\python\\working_34\\mincraft2d\\dirt.png'),
```

Some times in order to get it to work I have to show full path like above

```
    #a dictionary linking resources to textures
    textures =   {
                    DIRT    : pygame.image.load('dirt.png'),
                    GRASS   : pygame.image.load('grass.png'),
....

                    CLOUD   : pygame.image.load('cloud.png'),
                    RAIN    : pygame.image.load('rain.png'),
                    THUNDER : pygame.image.load('thunder.png'),
                    TORNADO : pygame.image.load('tornado.png')
             }
```

**I get error at line 261 which begins with**         if randomNumber == 0:

```
    #pick a random number between 0 and 20
    randomNumber = random.randint(0,20)
    #if a zero, then the weather is TORNADO
    if randomNumber == 0:
        WEATHER = TORNADO
    #water if the random number is a 1 or a 2
    elif randomNumber in [1,2]:
        WEATHER = THUNDER
    elif randomNumber in [3,4,5,6,7,8]:
        WEATHER = RAIN
    else:
        WEATHER = CLOUD
```

Comment: Please describe what the problem you're having is

Comment: I get a indent error on line 261     I will add to above

Comment: If you're getting an "IndentationError" . . . did you try checking the indentation?

Comment: I did try moving it around and testing it I think the problem goes further than that

Comment: Make sure that there are no tabs, replace all tabs in the code with 4 spaces.

Comment: yes, no tabs using editpadpro which does some formatting, I think it has more do with maybe the location of the loop I add the full file untouched and as is current

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what the code looks like to me.. (for the first problem, line 259).

```
    #a list of resources
WEATHER = [CLOUD,RAIN,THUNDER,TORNADO]  # <-- problem here.

    #loop through each weather type and choose weather type for it to be
    #pick a random number between 0 and 20
    randomNumber = random.randint(0,20)
        #if a zero, then the weather is TORNADO
        if yada yada ...
```

You need to indent the line starting WEATHER or dedent the line starting randomNumber.  Indentation is used in python for blocks of code.  There's nothing between the WEATHER and randomNumber line (like an if statement or a while statement) that would mean the randomNumber line should be indented relative to the WEATHER line.  Same with all the other indent problems you've got.  There's a similar problem with the if line that follows randomNumber assignment.  Get all your lines with the same depth of indentation unless there's a reason not to (e.g. the body of an if statement, but not the if statement itself).

To be clear.. what it should look like is this (all indented 4 spaces):

```
    #a list of resources
    WEATHER = [CLOUD,RAIN,THUNDER,TORNADO]  

    #loop through each weather type and choose weather type for it to be
    #pick a random number between 0 and 20
    randomNumber = random.randint(0,20)
    #if a zero, then the weather is TORNADO
    if yada yada ...
```

This will give you a little background http://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php   Also choosing a decent editor will often help find these bugs for you.  Here's a list http://pedrokroger.net/choosing-best-python-ide/

Also good on you for taking the time to do this with your kid.

Comment: I think the problem is that "There's nothing between the WEATHER and randomNumber line (like an if statement or a while statement)" in the rest of the code with simular function the is a line with a for before the random number generation. in that case its for the tiles.  I think maybe he forgot to have the random numbered for weather. Not sure where to start with that. I also will look into a better editor for us both.

Comment: From what I can see from the code there's no need for that weather line at all.  First he sets WEATHER to a list [CLOUD,RAIN,THUNDER,TORNADO]  then straight afterwards he goes into an if/then/elif/else statement which sets WEATHER to TORNADO or something depending on the random number.  So you can just comment out the WEATHER = [CLOUD,RAIN,THUNDER,TORNADO] line

Comment: As far as editors go.. those ones I listed were probably for professional programmers.  Check out this post instead, http://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/1e5tg9/new_to_python_what_ide_is_best_for_learningsimple  I quote "I would recomend Sublime Text 2.  Not really and IDE, and not just a text editor.  Writing in it, is like smearing honey over a naked Kiera Knightly"  Which does sound good.

Comment: I think I got the formatting fixed up, digging the color scheme on the Sublime Text 2 and I commented out WEATHER = [CLOUD,RAIN,THUNDER,TORNADO] line but that just uncovered  NameError: name 'RAIN' is not defined  in the beginning where he lists all of his images or textures                     RAIN    : pygame.image.load('rain.png'),

Comment: It's not defined.  Your son has added it to the code by the looks and not defined it.  You need to go and add it up at line 31.. something like RAIN = 13

Comment: I did that for RAIN and the rest no errors just get black screen,but  I think those definitions are for the inventory to craft item. I do get a warning for the images libpng warning: iCCP: know  incorrect s RBG profile

Comment: I now get no errors but it just displays black screen.  fixed the two images to be SRGB instead photostop s rgb